# Excel INDEX MATCH IF greater than 10%

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to summarise an excel sheet where only the results that are higher than 10% are included in a separate sheet.

I know how to use `INDEX MATCH`, and need to go one further and only `INDEX MATCH` when `VALUE` is greater than 10%'

See table, where top sheet is found in other tabs and summary sheet will populate only the description where greater than 10%.

I'm sure there is an elegant way of doing this, and I seem to over complicate my steps, breaking them down into extra columns for if, then trying to match, then return the referenced value, but ultimately I fail.

[image]

Why can't I just use `Index Match (0.1,C:C,-1)`? Where 0.1 is 10%. Col `E`, unformatted 'real' value is 0.01-0.15. Excel fails if I try `=Match(0.1,E:E,-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake with `MATCH`. To use `greater than` your data set must be arranged in descending order. Likewise with `less than` your data set must be arranged in ascending order.

I'd suggest using the something like the following formula instead

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$5)/($D$3:$D$5>0.1),ROW(1:1)))
```

which returns

[image]

Comment: Instead of the Volitile Indirect, consider using Index(A:A, Aggregate... )

Comment: Thanks for the nice edits Tom. I will attempt to replicate in the future! Oh and your answer!

Comment: @Tom: Can I ask your thinking with the 4 inputs to the AGGREGATE function? Googling, I can see that 15='Small' (why 'small'?) sub-function, and 6=Exclude errors (which I get). Considering the last 2 inputs I am not yet across; are you using the ref1, ref2 or the array,k-th percentile option for AGGREGATE?

Comment: edit: OK I see you are using the logic and error returns in a useful/meaningful way, before flushing them out after wrapping AGGREGATE(a,6,c). Nice trick, and I like this function!

Comment: I used small importantly as It can find the items in an unordered list. 15 allows me to enter an array into small instead of a range. The aggregate function is a very powerful formula. Well worth reading up on when you have time (if you haven't already)